# What is the difference between visual studio 2015 and visual studio 2015 Experimental Instance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

What is user role in this experiment ?
Would be good to get extended answer

Comment: "user role"???  It would be good to get an extended question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Experimental Instance actually lets you load and debug Visual Studio Extension Packages (VSIX).

So it is not so much an Experimental IDE in terms of features, it is more a scratch space where you can load potentially troublesome VSIX packages and if it crashes you have your normal IDE to revert back too.

please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx and http://www.dwmkerr.com/the-visual-studio-experimental-instance/